# How can I sort out formula of carmax.com calculator?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I sort out formula of this website?

[Car Max Calculator](https://www.carmax.com/car/15871582)

Here is screenshot:

[Click here](http://prntscr.com/lbcl14)

Comment: What sort of formula are you looking for? Is it for finance options? There are several websites you can look at for loan payment calculations - you need to decide whether you want to charge "simple interest" or "compound interest".

Comment: @halfer Can you give me any example in code pen?

Comment: I _could_ do your web-searching for you, but making an attempt on this is your job, as a software engineer. Research is a key skill for a software engineer. If you have searched and not found anything, please let me know what phrases you searched for, and what search engines you used.

Comment: It would be helpful for us to know where you are stuck, too. Is the problem calculating the monthly payments? Inserting elements into the DOM?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In short:** there is no secret formula (sorry plankton)

**In depth:**

This website (just like many others) is built on API ([Wikipedia to the rescue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)). You can use an API reference documentation to find your way to the core functionality of a given service (website, app, etc.). In your case, it would be something like [this](https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/robnewton/CarMax.Store.Gateway/1.0.0)

Anyhow, if you like to see the *"internals"* of this website (or any other) you may start by inspecting the network traffic of this website. You can do so by opening the developer tools of your web browser (in most browsers, pressing `F12` will do the trick)

Here is a screenshot from my machine to help you see what I mean
[image]